# Set Theory: proofs for subsets and complements

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A$ and $B$ be subsets of a universe $U$ (so $A \subseteq U$ and $B \subseteq U$)

a. Prove that $A^{c} \cap B^{c} \subseteq (A \cap B)^{c}$

b. Define specific sets $A, B, U$ such that the containment is $strict$, where $A^{c} \cap B^{c} \subset (A \cap B)^{c}$

c. Define specific sets $A, B, U$ such that $A^{c} \cap B^{c} = (A \cap B )^{c}$

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, many find the use of imperative ("Prove", etc.) to be rude when asking for help; please consider rewriting your post.

Comment: @MatthewConroy Thanks Matthew, I really appreciate it. I surely will think twice before posting questions in the future and will provide more context as in what I already know :)

Comment: @user124884 You can also edit your own posts to improve the question if you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(a)

Let $x \in A^c \cap B^c \iff x\in A^c$ and $x \in B^c \iff x \notin A$ and $x \notin B \iff x \in (A \cap B)^c$

(b) Let $U = \{ 1, 2, 3\}$, $A = \{1,2 \}$, and $B = \{2 \}$.

So we have $A^c \cap B^c = \{3 \} \cap \{ 1 ,3\} = \{ 3\} \subset (A \cap B)^c = (\{1,2 \} \cap \{ 2\})^c = \{2\}^c = \{1, 3 \}$

(c) Take everything to be the same set, or better yet empty. If you don't like that and want to see numbers, we can try $U = \{1, 2 \}$ and $A = \{1 \}$ and $B = A $.

Comment: Thank you so much, and I apologize starting a "question" with the word PROVE. Please forgive the lack of context of this question :)